# How to write multiple lines over a socket in c++

Tags: c++, sockets

quite new to socket programming and just had a short question, i'm trying to display multiple lines of output on my client from the server but I can't seem to get the lines to separate. Any help appreciated.

Server:

```
void help(int sock)
{
    n = write(sock,"Commands:\n",11);
    n = write(sock,"HELP -> Displays usable commands\n",34);
    n = write(sock,"BROADCAST 'message' -> Sends 'message' to every user\n",54);
    n = write(sock,"SEND 'user' 'message' -> Sends 'message' to 'user'\n",52);
    n = write(sock,"DISPLAY -> Displays all current users\n",39);
    n = write(sock,"LEAVE -> Ends the current session\n",35);
}
```

Client:

```
while(buffer[0] != 'L')
    {
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
        cout << buffer << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);` do something with `n`.

Comment: Another hint: you don't need the `bzero()`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth should i make a small for loop and a temp string and get the buffer characters into the temp string and output that?

Comment: YAH: You can't count on TCP to not mush your writes together. To optimize network usage, it buffers your writes, truying to pack as much into as few transmitted packets as possible given the current network conditions. Data gets to you when it gets to you in chunks you have next to no control over, but it gets to you in the correct order.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah that makes sense, but shouldn't the `\n` characters force a new line?

Comment: TCP doesn't know a newline from a hole in the ground. It's just another anonymous byte. In addition you can't count on all of one write being available when you read. It can get cut off part way through one of your write transactions and have to wait for the rest to arrive. That first read might get as few as one byte, no newline, and no terminating NULL. `cout` will really hate that. You have to loop at the receiver until you're sure you got the whole message before you do anything with it.

Comment: @user4581301 So something like a `while(*buffer != '*')` with a `n = read(sockfd,buffer,1)` inside the loop?

Comment: The easy way will be read and get n bytes, then `while (--n) { char ch = *buffer++; if (ch = '\n') { cout << accumulator.str() <<'\n'; accumulator.str(""); } else {accumulator << ch; }` where accumulator is a `std::stringstream` that will persist between calls to read.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @JasonLutz: note that `std:cout` is already buffered, so you don't really need an `accumulator` (although it does help with scanning for `LEAVE`), you can just `<<` each `char` that is received, and it will automatically flush to the console when its buffer is full or `'\n'` is written.  Also note that your original `write()` code is including the null terminators when sending the strings. That should be omitting in this situation.

Comment: Good point. I was using accumulator out of habit. Usually I'd have something like `if (process(accumulator.str()))` where the `cout` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues with your code:

1. your calls to `write()` are including the null terminators of the strings.  You should not be that in this situation.
2. your `read()` code is ignoring the return value of `read()`. Just because you ask for 255 bytes does not guarantee that you will receive 255 bytes.  The return value tells you how many bytes were actually received.  And the bytes that you do receive are not guaranteed to be null terminated, either, so you can't write the buffer as a plain `char*` pointer alone to `std::cout`, that will make it look for a null terminator.  `std::cout` has a `write()` method that you can use to specify how many `char`s are to be written.  Use the return value of `read()` for that purpose.
3. aside from that, you are assuming that call to `read()` will read a single complete line, so that you can check the first `char` in the last received buffer for the `L` of the final `LEAVE` line.  That is simply not true, and you can't rely on that.  TCP is a byte stream, `read()` is going to receive and return arbitrary amounts of data, depending on what is available in the socket's receive buffer.  If you need to read line-based data, you will have to accumulate the input bytes into a growing buffer of some kind and then scan that for line breaks as new data arrives.  You can then remove only completed lines from that buffer and process their content as needed.

Try something more like this instead:

```c
int writestr(int sock, const char *str)
{
    int n, len = strlen(str);
    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = write(sock, str, len);
        if (n < 0) return n;
        str += n;
        len -= n;
    }
    return 0;
}

void help(int sock)
{
    n = writestr(sock, "Commands:\n");
    n = writestr(sock, "HELP -> Displays usable commands\n");
    n = writestr(sock, "BROADCAST 'message' -> Sends 'message' to every user\n");
    n = writestr(sock, "SEND 'user' 'message' -> Sends 'message' to 'user'\n");
    n = writestr(sock, "DISPLAY -> Displays all current users\n");
    n = writestr(sock, "LEAVE -> Ends the current session\n");
}
```

```cpp
char buffer[256];
std::string data;
std::string::size_type pos, last_pos = 0;

while (true)
{
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (n <= 0) break;

    std::cout.write(buffer, n);

    data.append(buffer, n);

    pos = data.find('\n', last_pos);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string line = data.substr(0, pos);
        /* if you want to support CRLF line breaks, do this instead:
        std::string::size_type len = pos;
        if ((len > 0) && (data[len-1] == '\r'))
            --len;
        std::string line = data.substr(0, len);
        */

        data.erase(0, pos+1);

        if (line.compare(0, 5, "LEAVE") == 0)
            break;

        last_pos = 0;
    }
    else
        last_pos = data.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I understand that TCP works with bytes now, thanks for clarifying on that, It's my first time working with both sockets and shared memory and I'm slowly getting there. Really appreciate the help.